# In jinja2, how to include the same template twice but pass in different variables

Tags: python, jinja2

In jinja2, I am trying to dynamically create a html document using the template more than once. 
My python script looks like this:

```
# In my python script
env = Environment()
env.loader = FileSystemLoader('.')
base_template = env.get_template('base_template.html')

# each has the actual content and its associated template 
content1 = ("Hello World", 'content_template.html') 
content2 = ("Foo bar", 'content_template.html')


html_to_present = [content1[1], content2[1]]

# and render. I know this is wrong 
# as I am not passing the actual content, 
# but this is the part I am struggling with. More below
base_template.render(include_these=html_to_present, ).encode("utf-8"))
```

And my base template looks like this:

```
#################
# base_template.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for include_this in include_these %}
    {% include include_this %}
    {% endfor %}    
</body>
</html>
```

and `content_template.html` looks like this

```
# content_template.html
<div>
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Now my question is how do you dynamically set `content` variable in the `content_template.html` based on the value associated with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [*Jinja2 macros*](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros) to parameterise your templates.

A macro is like a Python function; you define a template snippet, plus the arguments it takes, and then you can call the macro just like you would a function.

I'd put the macros together into one macro template and [import](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import) that template into your base template. Pass in the names of the macros you want to use to the base template:

```
# content and macro name
content1 = ("Hello World", 'content_template') 
content2 = ("Foo bar", 'content_template')

base_template.render(include_these=[content1, content2]).encode("utf-8"))
```

This adds the `macro` context filter to the environment as well.

and in your `base_template.html` have:

```html
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for content, macroname in include_these %}
    {% macros[macroname](content) %}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

and the `macros.html` template:

```html
{% macro content_template(content) -%}
<div>
    {{ content }}
</div>
{%- endmacro %}
```